# Find max number in 2d array with thread

Tags: c, arrays, multithreading, pthreads

I want to create one thread for each row of my 2D array. Then each thread should find the max value in given row, but I can't wait for any thread to complete with `pthread_join`. So what should I do?

Comment: First, you should post some code that you tried and that did not work for you.

Comment: What do you mean with `i cant wait for any thread to complete with pthread_join`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand you want to split your 2D array into 1D arrays and pass them to threads, but you don't know what to do when each of these threads finds maximum in its "own" array - and  you don't want to pass this value to `pthread_exit()` and retrieve it by `pthread_join()` in the main thread.

You could use global array managed by the main thread for storing these values. Here's the idea (pseudocode):

```
int* max; // global

thread(...){
int localMax = 0;
...
max[rowIndex] = localMax;
}

// main thread:
max = malloc (rowCount * sizeof(int));
...
free(max);
```

Each thread finds local maximum `localMax` in given array (row) and stores it into array `max`.

But at the end you will have to use `pthread_join` so that you know that all threads have finished their work.